# express.js: Cannot read property 'module property name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to add a new product to my product list but for some reason, it's not working. Now I have tried the same process in many other projects yet I never stumbled across this problem. I can get data from the database but I can't add new data. Every time I try to add this error appears:

- Cannot read property 'name' of undefined. (node:13384) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
  (node:13384) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

this is my code

product module :

```
const ProductSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    code: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    quantity: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    price: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    image: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
    status: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: "In Stock",
      enum: ["In Stock", "Out Of Stock", "Low On Stock"],
    },
    internal_information: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = model("products", ProductSchema);
```

Route:

```
router.post("/add-product", async (req, res) => {
  await addProduct(req.body, res);
});
```

Util:

```
const addProduct = async (req, res) => {
  const prod = new Product({
    name: req.body.name,
    code: req.body.code,
    quantity: req.body.quantity,
    price: req.body.price,
    description: req.body.description,
    images: req.body.images,
    status: req.body.status,
    internal_information: req.body.internal_information,
  });

  await prod.save();
  return res.status(201).json({
    message: "Product has been added.",
    success: true,
  });
};
```

also I have these lines in index.js with some other code as well:

```
app.use("/api/products", require("./routes/products"));
app.use(bp.json());
```

Comment: you are passing `req.body` to `addProduct(req.body, res)`,  instead pass `req`

Comment: yeah that's the problem, when you create the object, req.body is undefined
`name: req.body.name,`
that's because you are passing req.body but receiving it as req

Comment: try debugging the code or at least adding some console.log() entries to see what's inside the variables, that will most probably help you

Comment: Oh thank you so much @Nilesh Patel that was the problem I didn't notice that thank you again.